# Moving duplicate rows from a subset of columns to another data frame in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Using Python and Pandas I want to find all columns with duplicate rows in a data frame and move them to another data frame. 
For example I might have:

```
cats, tigers, 3.5, 1, cars, 2, 5
cats, tigers, 3.5, 6, 7.2, 22.6, 5
cats, tigers, 3.5, test, 2.6, 99, 52.3
```

And I want cats, tigers, 3.5 in one data frame

```
cats, tigers, 3.5
```

and in another data frame I want

```
   1, cars, 2, 5
   6, 7.2, 22.6, 5
   test, 2.6, 99, 52.3
```

The code should check every column for repeat rows and only remove columns in which repeats occur in all rows.

1. Some of the cases none of the columns have repeats.
2. Some times more than just the first three columns have repeats. It should check all of the columns because repeats can occur in any column

How could I do this?

Comment: can you show us more information ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Method 1:
use `nunique` with `dropna=False`

```
m = df.nunique(dropna=False).eq(1)

df_dup = df.iloc[[0], m.values]

Out[121]:
      0       1    2
0  cats  tigers  3.5

df_notdup = df.loc[:, ~m]

Out[123]:
      3     4     5     6
0     1  cars   2.0   5.0
1     6   7.2  22.6   5.0
2  test   2.6  99.0  52.3
```

---

**Method 2:**
Use listcomp and on each columns check `duplicated` with option `keep=False` and check `all`

```
m = np.array([df[x].duplicated(keep=False).all() for x in df])

df_dup = df.loc[:, m]

Out[65]:
      0       1    2
0  cats  tigers  3.5
1  cats  tigers  3.5
2  cats  tigers  3.5
```

As @Moys mention, if you want only one row in `df_dup`, you may use `drop_duplicates` or simply `.head(1)` or `iloc`

```
df_dup = df.loc[:, m].head(1)
```

or

```
df_dup = df.iloc[[0], m]

Out[91]:
      0       1    2
0  cats  tigers  3.5
```

For not dup rows:

```
df_notdup = df.loc[:, ~m]

Out[75]:
      3     4     5     6
0     1  cars   2.0   5.0
1     6   7.2  22.6   5.0
2  test   2.6  99.0  52.3
```

Comment: Good solution. Up-voted.  I think you may just want to add `.drop_duplicates()` to `df_dup = df.loc[:, m]` to match OP's desired result.

Comment: @moys: I added to the answer. However, I prefer `head(1)` for shorter. I up-voted your solution too :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df.val.str.extract('([a-zA-Z ]+)', expand=False).str.strip().drop_duplicates()) #'val' is the column in which you have these values
print(df1)
```

**Output**

```
     val
0   ABCD
```

and

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df.val.str.extract('([0-9]+)', expand=False).str.strip().drop_duplicates()) #'val' is the column in which you have these values
print(df2)
```

**Output**

```
     val
0   1234
1   6578
2   4432
```

Comment: please provide data that represents your actual data. without it, it is difficult to assume what you have & what you want.

Comment: So, you want data till first 3 commas as one dataframe & the rest as another?